# Ubuntu mate 20.04 not showing networks

Tags: networking

Switched to Ubuntu mate and no WiFi networks are shown. No Ethernet shown either

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Add missing configuration file to network manager:

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

Restart network manager:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```